# The best way to trigger an event when the model.fetch is complete

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, marionette

I am looking for the best way to trigger an event when the fetch is completed.
This code works but I am curious to know if there is a better way to accomplish the following task.

```
var myApp = new Marionette.Application();

myApp.on("initialize:before", function () {
    this.currentUser = new UserModel();
    this.currentUser.fetch({
        complete: function () {
            myApp.vent.trigger('currentUser');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A successful [`fetch` triggers a `"change"` event](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-fetch):

> **fetch** `model.fetch([options])`
>
> [...] A `"change"` event will be triggered if the server's state differs from the current attributes.

So if the `fetch` does anything, there will be a `"change"` that you can listen for:

```
myApp.on("initialize:before", function () {
    this.currentUser = new UserModel();
    this.currentUser.on('change', function() {
        myApp.vent.trigger('currentUser');
    });
    this.currentUser.fetch();
});
```

That will also trigger a `"currentUser"` event if `this.currentUser` is changed in some other way and that might or might not be what you want. If you only want your function called once then your current `success` handler is probably the easiest thing to do; you could still use `on` and unbind the handler when it is called:

```
myApp.on("initialize:before", function () {
    var triggerCurrentUser = _.bind(function() {
        myApp.vent.trigger('currentUser');
        this.currentUser.off('change', triggerCurrentUser);
    }, this);

    this.currentUser = new UserModel();
    this.currentUser.on('change', triggerCurrentUser);
    this.currentUser.fetch();
});
```

You could also use [`_.once`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#once) but that would leave a no-op callback function kicking around and there's no need for that.

Comment: Actually I want my function called once when the model is fetched and not when it changes. So at this point what is the advantage to use `off `? Is it more recommendable than using a callback?

Comment: @LorraineBernard: Your current `success` handler is fine if you just want a one-shot callback. You'd usually only use `on` if you wanted multiple notifications or if the `this.currentUser.on()` and `this.currentUser.fetch()` were in different places in the source (i.e. using `success` wouldn't work due to state information being somewhere else).